# Why is my CSS grid-template-columns stacking and not being consistent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I have these carousel thumbnails that supposedly keep adding to the right until each of them reached the width of 120px and they'll go into the next row. These thumbnails are wrapped by a wrapper which its width fits its content.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel-thumbnail-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel-thumbnail mod-active">
    <img src="./img/project-slider-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-thumbnail">
    <img src="./img/project-slider-2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cg-carousel > .carousel-thumbnail-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  column-gap: 8px;
  width: fit-content; /** the width fits its content... */
  max-width: 100%; /** ...but can only grow not more than 100% of its parent's */
}

.cg-carousel > .carousel-thumbnail-wrapper > .carousel-thumbnail {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-xs);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 200px; /** each thumbnail has maximum 200px width */
}
```

Normally, if everything goes right it will show like this: [Images keep adding to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPBvB.png)

It does work like that **sometimes**. But when I refresh the page or go to another page back to back, for some reason they're stacking, like this: [Images suddenly stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgkdp.png)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: in your css, maybe try to set the `display` of `images` as `inline-block`, but i havent checked so that may not be the only problem

Comment: And please include your html for the element `.cg-carousel`

Comment: @AlphaHowl Setting display to `inline-block` doesn't do anything. And `.cg-carousel` doesn't have anything other than `width:100%` :/

Comment: Ok, and how many images / how long should it be before the images go to the next row?

Comment: @AlphaHowl they should keep adding and shrinking until each image reach the width of 120px. The initial width of each of them is 200px

Comment: So you want to dynamically resize the images (as new images are added) to make them smaller, until they reach a minimum width of 120px, when they should go to the next row. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much like that

Comment: Ok, i've got it, i think... Check my answer

Comment: Oh I was expecting it to point out what I did wrong with my code. But I would probably consider that to be my last resort if I reach dead end. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll explain. I'll just place your code in a snippet first.

Comment: So your code isn't wrong per se, but your selectors are a little off, and your images need a width of 100%, otherwise they will not resize - their parent will, but they will still remain their original size. So if you change your selectors so that they actually target the elements in your html, and set the width of the images to 100%, it should work perfectly. The javascript in my answer makes your code fully fool-proof as it combats any css issues older browsers may face. But if old browsers are not a problem, then check this fiddle to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/258b9x6e/1/

Comment: I'll embed this into a new answer for people in the future.

Comment: Hmm interesting, that's exactly what my code looks like. I guess it's the compatibility issue maybe. At first I was wondering if it has something to do with css bundling (that's how I got this weird behavior in the first place), but then I tried to import them manually and it still doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code isn't wrong per se, but your selectors are a little off, and your images need a `width` of `100%`, otherwise they will not resize - their parent will, but they will still remain their original size. So if you change your selectors so that they actually target the elements in your html, and set the width of the images to `100%`, it should work perfectly. The javascript in my other answer makes your code fully fool-proof as it combats any css issues older browsers may face. But if old browsers are not a problem, then use this answer. 
 **Below is a snippet. Here is a jsfiddle link if you want to resize the viewport, add images or play with the code in general: https://jsfiddle.net/258b9x6e/1/**

```css
.carousel-thumbnail-wrapper {width: 100%}

.carousel-thumbnail-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  column-gap: 8px;
  width: fit-content; /** the width fits its content... */
  max-width: 100%; /** ...but can only grow not more than 100% of its parent's */
}

.carousel-thumbnail {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-xs);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 200px; /** each thumbnail has maximum 200px width */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-thumbnail-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel-thumbnail mod-active">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-thumbnail">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will resize the images, to make them small enough to be able to fit on one row, until they are 120px in width, which is when they will no longer be shrunk, but moved to the next row. **This achieves the same results as my other answer, but also works on older browsers, at the expense of having to use JS. My other answer only works on newer browsers but does not need any JS**.

**Here, I've used 3 imgs but you can use as many as you would like** This is also responsive, so you can resize your browser and the images will still fit well.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img")[document.querySelectorAll("img").length-1].onload = re_calculate_image_width;


function re_calculate_image_width() {
  let count = document.querySelectorAll(".img-wrapper").length;
  document.querySelector(".outer-wrapper").style.setProperty("--how-many", (count).toString());
}

alert("Important: Read this: \n If you dynamically add more images, you MUST call the ***re_calculate_image_width*** function when the added images have finished ***loading***.");
```

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.6);
  --how-many: 5;
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: calc(90% / var(--how-many));
  height: auto;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```